# NSDate from NSString when time is in 24 hr format

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string of the format Jan 25, 2011 3:17 AM. I need to convert it to NSDate.
I used NSDateFormatter with format @"MMM d, yyyy h:mm a". It Works well if iphone time is in 12 hr format, but returns nil if time is in 24 hr format. Can any one help me with this????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Capital H is used for 24 hour format. Don't 24 hour times usually exclude the AM/PM part?  If so, your format string should be: `@"MMM d yyyy H:mm"`.

[Here's a reference for Unicode date format strings.](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: It is strange to see a clock that says `17:00 pm`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in NSDateFormatter. You can work around it by manually setting a locale on the date formatter:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease]];
```